# Подскажите почему данный скрипт сборки ядра не будет работать?

Tags: linux, sh

```
#!/bin/sh

for i in  "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" 
do
    time -p make -kpkg  -j $i clean 

    fakeroot make -kpkg -j $i --initrd --append-to-version=-custom kernel_image kernel_headers
done
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

работать-то будет, но результат, вероятно, получится не тот, что вы ожидаете.

а вот если убрать пробел между `make` и `-kpkg`, чтобы получился не вызов программы `make` с опциями `-k -p -k -g` (последняя из которых вообще отсутствует у этой программы, что приводит к её аварийному завершению, а с опцией `-p` программа лишь выводит список правил и переменных и сразу завершается), а вызов скрипта `make-kpkg`, то должно получиться довольно близко к вашим ожиданиям.

p.s. заключать цифры в кавычки в данном случае совсем не обязательно.